# Entity Framework Core OwnsOne Creates Separate Tables, Rather than adding properties to the Same Table as Expected

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.1, owned-types

I thought that Entity Framework Core owned types by default get added to the same table as their owner. But I'm not seeing this in the migration.

Would someone clue me in here?

Is there a way to get the desired migration with Name properties added directly to the Person table?

```
public class Person
{
    public Name Name { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> person)
    {
          person.OwnsOne(p => p.Name);
    }
}
```

`dotnet ef migrations add DidNotSeeThatComing`
results in

```
public partial class DidNotSeeThatComing : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Name",
            columns: table => new
            {
                FirstName = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", nullable: true),
                LastName = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar", nullable: true),
                PersonId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Name", x => x.PersonId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Name_Person_PersonId",
                    column: x => x.PersonId,
                    principalTable: "Person",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your thought is correct - by default it goes to the same table as the owner, and I can't reproduce the issue. Do you have clean repro project?

Comment: @IvanStoev verified works as expected with a clean repo project

Comment: Any unusual code in the project where this is happening? Like loops on model entities/reflection and calling `ToTable`?

Comment: Ugg I did this to myself with

            foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Name;
            }

Comment: He-he, so at the end it was unusual model entities loop :) Glad that you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I created this myself unwittingly with this configuration code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
   {
       entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Name;
   }
}
```

Here is the workaround I'm using

```
[Owned] // Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
public class Name { ... }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
   {
       if(!entity.ClrType.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<OwnedAttribute>().Any())
       {
            entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Name;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: [Owned] is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId {get;set;}
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> person)
    {
        person.OwnsOne(p => p.Name,
            nCls =>
            {
                nCls.HasOne(n => n.Person);
                nCls.HasKey(n => new {n.Id, n.PersonId});
                nCls.HasForeignKey(m => m.PersonId);
                nCls.ToTable(nCls.OwnedEntityType.ClrType.Name);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

this should get you something like:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
// the table names are lower case because my convention is to generate all names in snake_case

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "persons",
        columns: table => new
        {
            id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("pk_persons", x => x.id);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "name",
        columns: table => new
        {
            id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            person_id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
            first_name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            last_name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("pk_name", x => new { x.id, x.person_id });
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "fk_name_persons_person_id",
                column: x => x.person_id,
                principalTable: "persons",
                principalColumn: "id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Davious i had exact the same problem today thanks for sharing your solution. Here is my solution where you don't need the `OwnedAttribute` because you can also use `entity.IsOwned()`. I always try to do all confiugration via the DbContext.

```
///[Owned] // Not needed anymore
public class Name { ... }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelbuilder.Entity<Person>().OwnsOne(p => p.Name)

   foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
   {
       if(!entity.IsOwned())
       {
            entity.Relational().TableName = entity.Name;
       }
   }
}
```